# Rails and threading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, nginx

I'm trying to make a Rails 4 application that makes a lot of http requests to some API handle more traffic, originally the code in the controller looks like this:

```
def index
  @var1 = api_call some_params1
  @var2 = api_call some_params2
  @var3 = api_call some_params3
  @var4 = api_call some_params4
  @var5 = api_call some_params5
end
```

I did some googling around and ended up refactoring it as so:

```
def index
  @var1 = Thread.new { api_call some_params1 }.value
  @var2 = Thread.new { api_call some_params2 }.value
  @var3 = Thread.new { api_call some_params3 }.value
  @var4 = Thread.new { api_call some_params4 }.value
  @var5 = Thread.new { api_call some_params5 }.value
end
```

Am I doing this right? Or am I instead supposed to call `join` on those threads somewhere?

Is this safe for production or is there something I should be tweaking, maybe in the Nginx or passenger configs?

Comment: You may want to consider using [ActiveJob](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html) for this instead of arbitrary threads. Code like this could create thousands of untamed threads that could eventually crash your Ruby process if not the whole server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Am I doing this right?

There are no issues in your code but I don't think that using threads makes a lot of sense in your code example since you're executing requests one after another anyway.
If you want to make parallel requests then you should do it like this instead:

```rb
threads = [params1, params2, ...].map { |p| Thread.new { api_call(p) } }
values = threads.map(&:value)
```

> Am I doing this right? Or am I instead supposed to call `join` on those threads somewhere?

Both `join` and `value` calls will wait for a thread to finish but `value` is more convenient for you there if you want to retrieve a value returned from a thread. `value` is using `join` under the hood.

> Is this safe for production or is there something I should be tweaking, maybe in the Nginx or passenger configs?

You don't need to tweak anything to use threads and it is generally safe to use them in production (if you're using [MRI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_MRI) then [GIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_interpreter_lock) prevents deadlocks). You just need to be aware that if you're using a lot of threads then you'll be using a lot of extra memory. And using threads don't always improve performance of a program. For example, due to GIL there is not much point in using threads for executing CPU-intensive code even on a multicore machine.

Comment: Even better: `threads = [ params1, params2, ... ].map { |p| Thread.new { api_call(p) } }`